# Getting followers and following with Instagram APIs

Tags: php, api, server, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am studying to integrate Instagram into my app.But I have some confusion.
I found 2 API document: https://www.instagram.com/developer/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/. They have differences about supporting API Endpoints as well as how to use. So, what are they and what should we use the one for my app?

I need to get followers and following of user. But I could not found any APIs support for that functions.

Could you please help, I really need it for my app.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> As of 1st of June 2016. Now you're only able to get the list of your
>   own followers/followings.

You can [read about it here](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/facebook-instagram-api-shut-down/).

This api is used to get own followers/following list :

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Manzurul.
I also found it from Instagram API document. But I dont know why there are some websites can collect user information from Instagram, here is example: https://socialblade.com/instagram/user/therock

Comment: where to get this access token?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the documentation found on the Instagram website, which will show you lots of end points but only let you use [these two](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) if your app has not been approved. At least that was the case until a few days ago, when accessing those endpoints started throwing off CORS errors.

Comment: Thank you David!

What is approval for Instagram API? I only see 2 user end points from your link. Do you have any documents for extra API with approved app or account?

Comment: Ray it looks like there were some more endpoints when I first checked out those docs, and they removed them on 12/11/18. There is a section that allows you to ask for more than sandbox permissions for your app, but now that the API is deprecated they might be ignoring that completely. It does look like they are shifting to the same Graph API they use with facebook. To answer your question about socialblade, well, I can't say for sure, but I'm pretty sure if you have enough money you can get whatever access you want. If you're a small fry developer like me, you might be out of luck!

Comment: Yes, haha. I am developing a small app, so its too difficult for me to access necessary APIs from Instagram. I am trying to study on Graph API. I hope that we will have more endpoints from it.

Thank you very much, David