# Is there any way to get the list of instagram followers using basic display api?

Tags: javascript, python, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of instagram followers by using instagram basic display api but it dosen't work

Is there any way to use a some kind of script to get the list after loging in with the api. I don't like to use instagram private api as it asks to input both username and password

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that anymore, since Meta had been nerfed their Instagram API to only, literally, display the basic info of one's account.

Here's a snippet from [an TechCrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/facebook-instagram-api-shut-down/) about such ordeal,
"Now an Instagram spokesperson tells TechCrunch that “Effective today, Instagram is speeding up the previously announced deprecation of the Instagram API Platform” as part of Facebook’s work to protect people’s data. **The APIs for follower lists, relationships, and commenting on public content will cease to function immediately.** The December 11th, 2018 deprecation of public content reading APIs and the 2020 deprecation of basic profile info APIs will happen as scheduled, but it’s implemented rate limit reductions on them now."

Shout-out to Manzurul for their explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740031/getting-followers-and-following-with-instagram-apis).